# Чем может быть вызвана ошибка "Can't bind to local 8700 for debugger"?

Tags: android

При каждом запуске приложение на эмуляторе студия выдает данную ошибку, Gradle не делает никаких замечаний. С чем это связано?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198646/cant-bind-to-local-xxxx-for-debugger - может помочь

Comment: Это может быть связано с параллельной работой двух инструментов, использующих adb-соединение. У меня это выскакивает когда одновременно работают студия и эклипс или девайс монитор, запущенный не через меню студии

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, что порт 8700 уже занят кем-то другим и отладчик не может его использовать. Чтобы понять кем, можно воспользоваться утилитой netstat.

От себя замечу, что отлаживать на эмуляторе - это себя не уважать, а если подключить даже самый дешевый девайс - жизнь станет гораздо легче.